# How to determine cause of slow requests in Flask?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm developing a Flask web app with Docker and I've noticed that it hangs every few requests. Sometimes the request will completely time out and I'll receive a message from Docker saying:

[1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:8).

How can I find out the source of these slowdowns? I've already enabled response time tracking and it shows me that the delay is caused almost always in the first request (shown below), but I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the message it gives me:

[31/Mar/2017:22:36:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 56659 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" in 529927µs

Thanks!

Comment: docker for mac?

Comment: Yep, running on Sierra

Comment: There's been quite a few issues regarding performance and docker for mac.  It's not an ideal solution but try using one of the docker toolbox installs that use docker-machine (e.g. virtualbox)